# Jenkins role / group based UI to isolate build jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have got a requirement in Jenkins to our new instance, there are around 10 teams who use it and I'm looking if I could setup security strategy setup to separate out users:

1. Each team/group should be able to view/manage their own build jobs etc.
2. Should be able to manage their own transformations.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you please share how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin).
From plugin info:

> This plugin adds a new role-based strategy to ease and fasten users management. This strategy allows:
>
> - Creating global roles, such as admin, job creator, anonymous, etc., allowing to set Overall, Slave, Job, Run, View and SCM permissions on
>     a global basis.
> - Creating project roles, allowing to set only Job and Run permissions on a project basis.
> - Creating slave roles, allowing to set node-related permissions. Assigning these roles to users.

Comment: can you email via pipeline code a particular role/group?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy) plugin. I'm using it and it works well.

> This plugin adds a new role-based strategy to ease and fasten users management. This > > strategy allows:
>
> - Creating global roles, such as admin, job creator, anonymous, etc.,
>     allowing to set > Overall, Slave, Job, Run, View and SCM permissions
>     on a global basis.
> - Creating project roles, allowing to set only Job
>     and Run permissions on a project basis.
> - Creating slave roles,
>     allowing to set node-related permissions.
> - Assigning these roles to
>     users